# CORS Origin Request Blocked - What can I do from the client?

Tags: ajax, request, cors, http-headers, axios

I'm doing a request from my local server and:

- I'm getting 200 and the data (as far as I can see in the network tab of the developer  console)
- **If I make the request with POSTMAN it works fine.**
- I'm not getting the data in my client. Instead of that I'm getting the following object:

> ```
> { _40: 0
> _55: null
> _65: 0
> _72: null }
> ```

The developer console gives me this feedback:

> Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at https://theurlthatiwanttoget.herokuapp.com/something. (Reason: CORS request did not succeed).

My request:

```
await axios.get('https://theurlthatiwanttoget.herokuapp.com/something', {
            headers: {"Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*"}
});
```

**My question is: Can I do something from the client or I can be sure that the problem is that is not autorized in the server?**

Comment: hi the mentioned url is yours or not because you have to set permission in the controller to access someone's else data

Comment: See the *How to use a CORS proxy to get around “No Access-Control-Allow-Origin header” problems* section of the answer at https://stackoverflow.com/a/43881141/441757

Comment: Thanks! @sideshowbarker That answer fixed my problem.

Answer (score 0):

you can create proxy.conf.json file

containing

```
{
  "/api": {
    "target": "http://your address/",
    "secure": true,
    "changeOrigin": true
  }
}
```

and run

serve command with  --proxy-config proxy.conf.json